# Android layout preview not matching with device

Tags: android, android-layout

Acc to the definition of a dp, 10dp should be same on devices having same dimensions irrespective of density. Then why is the layout preview in Android Studio not matching with the layout when I am running it in my mobile? I am using pixel XL in Android Studio preview and I am running it on Samsung J7 prime.  Both are 5.5" diagonally but with different densities.Layout code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/ll"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
  tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
  tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="147dp"
    android:layout_height="173dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="454dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="248dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="122dp"
    android:layout_height="116dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/progressBar2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="494dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.518" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[The screenshot of the app:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cktq2.png)

[Here is the picture of preview:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQjYF.png)

Comment: The widgets are not overlapping as it should be.

Comment: Please put screenshots here on the website, instead of a link that might get removed in the future.

Comment: I need more stars/badges to do that

Comment: Oh I forgot about this. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem of the IDE that shows you this error, what you do is everytime you use widget, in that always use the width as **wrap_content** or **match_parent** it is because the Preview which your getting is slightly different from what the natural phone looks like.

For height you can give you own height. The width of the screen creates an issue.

*If in wrap_content if you find the issue in size then you can follow like this in order to get the desired result.*

```
<ProgressBar 
  android:width="match_parent"
  android:height="115dp"
  android:marginLeft="20dp"
  androidMarginRight="20dp">
```

You can achieve the desired width, you can adjust the value of the margin nothing else.

The benefit of doing thing like will give you the desired result in the phone as it will take up the full space of the width of the phone (Real One) and now adjust the margin according to it.

Try it and then tell me whether you are getting some result or not.

**EDITS**

Do like this in your layout in order to adjust

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/facebookButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="13dp"
                android:paddingBottom="11dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/googleButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Do like this for your problem.

Comment: For height, I can use scroll view, but the width is the problem. The actual layouts are quite complicated with widgets placed haphazardly without any ordered fashion.

Comment: I'm not getting what are you saying but to be very frank user **match_parent** as the width and adjust the margin according to it you will not get any problem. Try it.

Comment: If there are two widgets side by side separated by a small gap in between, how can I use match parent as width?

Answer (score 0):

My guess, is that since you used percentage for the positioning of the views, yet the normal size of them (wrap_content, or fixed sizes you used), the result would be different across different device displays.

On some cases, they would overlap, and on some, they won't.

I suggest you to try to run it on multiple displays, to confirm this. Try to change orientation and try on various emulator configurations, for example.

To solve this issue, there are multiple solutions, depends on your needs:

1. size and position must match : either both are percentage, or both are fixed sizes.
2. create better relations between the views, that will always work

Comment: where have I used percentage?

Comment: You used the attributes of "layout_constraintHorizontal_bias" and "layout_constraintVertical_bias", for example.

Comment: Try in the preview to show the same exact configuration of your device. I believe you will get the same result as of your device.

Comment: I havent introduced the percentages they come up automatically. I will try using relative layout

Comment: That's one of the purposes of using ConstraintLayout. I'm sure you can still use it, but I'm not experienced enough with it. I still use the old ones: FrameLayout, RelativeLayout, LinearLayout...

Comment: When I am previewing in exact device configuration it appears correctly. But then a general question should I create layouts for different screen sizes or different densities?

Comment: You should do everything you can to avoid creating multiple layouts, one for each density/resolution/screen size. It isn't practical. Don't fight the fragmentation of devices. You won't win. Think of a solution that will fit your needs in all cases. Of course, this doesn't mean you should never do this, but just depends on what you need. I suggest to do it only in rare cases, and to as fewer configurations as possible.